# Join and update large table in Mysql

Tags: mysql

Table one has:

```
id, new_id, col1, col2
```

Table two has:

```
id, col1, col2
```

Table one is over a million rows and table two is about 250K.

What I want to do in a single query is:

```
SET   t1.new_id = t2.id 
WHERE t1.col1   = t2.col1
AND   t1.col2   = t2.col2
AND   t1.new_id IS NULL
```

What I have right now is:

```
UPDATE t1
LEFT JOIN t2
ON  t1.new_id IS NULL
AND t1.col1 = t2.col1
AND t1.col2 = t2.col2
SET t1.new_id = t2.id
```

I think it can't be right. It's so slow it's never finishing... thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried it on a smaller sample?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax of your query is fine.  Except, the filter on `t1` should go in the `where` clause:

```
UPDATE t1 LEFT JOIN
       t2
       ON  t1.col1 = t2.col1 AND t1.col2 = t2.col2
SET t1.new_id = t2.id
WHERE t1.new_id IS NULL
```

Or, use an `inner join`:

```
UPDATE t1 JOIN
       t2
       ON t1.new_id IS NULL AND  t1.col1 = t2.col1 AND t1.col2 = t2.col2
SET t1.new_id = t2.id;
```

The `LEFT JOIN` keeps all rows in the first table regardless of the `ON` clause.  That means that your formulation is updating all the rows in `t1`, which may account for the performance problem.  Either using a `where` clause for filters on the first table or using an `inner join` should fix this aspect of the problem.

In addition, indexes would help.  I would recommend the following:  `t2(col1, col2, id)`, `t1(new_id, col1, col2)`.

Comment: Thanks, I'm sure it works, but they were both taking a long time for me, but then I wasn't dealing with much memory (4gb). I ended up creating the indexes and writing a script that loops over t2 and updates t1. It was quite fast no doubt due to the indexes.